# If a number from one data frame fits a condition defined by another data frame, then print the information from both datasets

Tags: r

I have two large data frames with head() below:

Data frame one:

```
family_name st_pos
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 AluSp        26791
2 AluJo        31436
3 AluSx        39624
4 AluSz6       40738
5 AluYe5       51585
6 AluSc        62160
```

Data frame two:

```
external_gene_name start_position end_position
1             ATP1A2      160115759    160143591
2               GCLM       93885199     93909456
3                TPR      186311652    186375693
4             VPS13D       12230030     12512047
5              SZRD1       16352575     16398145
6             ATP2B4      203626561    203744081
```

What I want to do is that if the number in st_pos from data frame one is larger than the "start_position" and smaller than the "end_position", then I'd like to print a new table with the column names indicated below.

```
external_gene_name    family_name     st_pos
```

I'm really new to R and I don't know even where to start with this.
Thank you so much for "exponentiate" my learning curve.

Comment: To be clear, the matching of the two tables is done through the rownames 1, 2, 3... ?

Comment: Where is your chromosome number? What you really want is [`GenomicRanges`](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/GenomicRanges/inst/doc/GenomicRangesIntroduction.html) not to implement this yourself.

Comment: No. They are not matched. The role numbering is irrelevant. I forgot to delete those sorry! @Rémi Coulaud

Comment: @Ian Campbell  it's already down to chromosome 1. I pulled the gene data from biomaRt. I'd like to get a list of Alu repeats for a list of genes I have and RepeatMasker doesn't give the information on the name of the gene but only the start and end positions for a particular repeat element. So I'm just gonna have to do this myself unless there are database out there with this info that I'm not aware of. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `GenomicRanges` is specifically designed to approach this problem.

As you may know, none of the sample of Alus overlaps the genes you provided. So I made some up.

```
library(GenomicRanges)
Alus <- GRanges(seqnames = "chr1",
                ranges = IRanges(start = df1$st_pos, width = 1),
                names = df1$family_name)
Alus
#GRanges object with 6 ranges and 1 metadata column:
#      seqnames    ranges strand |    names
#         <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> | <factor>
#  [1]     chr1 160115859      * |    AluSp
#  [2]     chr1  93885299      * |    AluJo
#  [3]     chr1 186312452      * |    AluSx
#  [4]     chr1  12230230      * |   AluSz6
#  [5]     chr1 203627561      * |   AluYe5
#  [6]     chr1     62160      * |    AluSc

Genes <- GRanges(seqnames = "chr1",
                 ranges = IRanges(start = df2$start_position, end = df2$end_position),
                 names = df2$external_gene_name)
Genes
#GRanges object with 6 ranges and 1 metadata column:
#      seqnames              ranges strand |    names
#         <Rle>           <IRanges>  <Rle> | <factor>
#  [1]     chr1 160115759-160143591      * |   ATP1A2
#  [2]     chr1   93885199-93909456      * |     GCLM
#  [3]     chr1 186311652-186375693      * |      TPR
#  [4]     chr1   12230030-12512047      * |   VPS13D
#  [5]     chr1   16352575-16398145      * |    SZRD1
#  [6]     chr1 203626561-203744081      * |   ATP2B4
```

Then you can use `findOverlaps` to find overlaps between the two ranges:

```
Overlaps <- findOverlaps(Genes,Alus)
data.frame(Genes[queryHits(Overlaps),],Alus[subjectHits(Overlaps),])
#  seqnames     start       end  width strand  names seqnames.1   start.1     end.1 width.1 strand.1 names.1
#1     chr1 160115759 160143591  27833      * ATP1A2       chr1 160115859 160115859       1        *   AluSp
#2     chr1  93885199  93909456  24258      *   GCLM       chr1  93885299  93885299       1        *   AluJo
#3     chr1 186311652 186375693  64042      *    TPR       chr1 186312452 186312452       1        *   AluSx
#4     chr1  12230030  12512047 282018      * VPS13D       chr1  12230230  12230230       1        *  AluSz6
#5     chr1 203626561 203744081 117521      * ATP2B4       chr1 203627561 203627561       1        *  AluYe5
```

If there were multiple overlaps per gene, there would be multiple rows.

**Sample Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(family_name = structure(c(3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
2L), .Label = c("AluJo", "AluSc", "AluSp", "AluSx", "AluSz6", 
"AluYe5"), class = "factor"), st_pos = c(160115859L, 93885299L, 
186312452L, 12230230L, 203627561L, 62160L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))

df2 <- structure(list(external_gene_name = structure(c(1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 
4L, 2L), .Label = c("ATP1A2", "ATP2B4", "GCLM", "SZRD1", "TPR", 
"VPS13D"), class = "factor"), start_position = c(160115759L, 
93885199L, 186311652L, 12230030L, 16352575L, 203626561L), end_position = c(160143591L, 
93909456L, 186375693L, 12512047L, 16398145L, 203744081L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```